# How to extend values on y-axis with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to measure 8 emotions across political parties in the U.S., however, data for only 4 emotions show up (I've attached an image). How can I include all feelings? I've also included the code below and screen shot here:

[image: ggplot image in R]

Here is the survey question and rating scale pertaining to the data:

Below is a list of feelings or moods that could be caused by an object. Please use the list below to describe how the U.S. FEDERAL parties (and its elected officials) make you feel. If the word definitely describes how a party makes you feel, then choose the number 5. If you decide that the word does not at all describe how the party makes you feel, then choose the number 1. Use the intermediate numbers between 1 and 5 to indicate responses between these two extremes.

[image: Rating Scales]

My code:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(mydata2$PARTYID_Strength, mydata2$mean.traitdem, 
                 color = mydata2$mean.traitdem)) +
  ggtitle("Political Party Affiliation and Feelings Towards the National Democratic Party") +
  xlab("Political Party Identification") +
  ylab("Feelings Towards Democratic Party")+
  xlim("Strong Democrat", "Not Very Strong Democrat",
       "Strong Republican", "Not Very Strong Republican",
       "Independent", "Independent - Democrat",
       "Independent - Republican", "Other")+
  ylim("Delighted", "Angry", "Happy", "Annoyed", "Joy", "Hateful", "Relaxed", "Disgusted") +
  theme(legend.position= "right", axis.text.x= element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 0.8))+
    scale_color_continuous(name = "Degrees of Emotion", 
                           breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                           labels = c("1","2","3","4","5")) + 
    theme(legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"))
```

Sample of my data:

```
> dput(head(mydata2, 30))
structure(list(PARTYID = c(1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2), PARTYID_Other = 
c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "Green", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), PARTYID_Strength = c(1, 
7, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 7, 5, 4, 6, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 2, 6, 3), PARTYID_Strength_Other = c("NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "Green", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), THERM_Dem = c(80, 
65, 85, 30, 76, 15, 55, 62, 90, 95, 73, 70, 98, 80, 0, 62, 10, 
70, 100, 32, 70, 100, 75, 0, 74, 60, 55, 10, 86, 39), THERM_Rep = c(1, 
45, 10, 5, 14, 14, 0, 4, 10, 3, 0, 0, 37, 10, 70, 38, 50, 31, 
0, 54, 50, 0, 20, 100, 20, 0, 14, 30, 12, 81), Gender = c("Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Non-binary", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Male"), `MEAN Age` = c(29.5, 49.5, 29.5, 39.5, 29.5, 
21, 39.5, 39.5, 29.5, 65, 29.5, 39.5, 65, 59.5, 49.5, 49.5, 39.5, 
29.5, 21, 29.5, 59.5, 21, 39.5, 65, 21, 39.5, 21, 21, 59.5, 65
), Age = c("25 - 34", "45 - 54", "25 - 34", "35 - 44", "25 - 34", 
"18 - 24", "35 - 44", "35 - 44", "25 - 34", "65+", "25 - 34", 
"35 - 44", "65+", "55 - 64", "45 - 54", "45 - 54", "35 - 44", 
"25 - 34", "18 - 24", "25 - 34", "55 - 64", "18 - 24", "35 - 44", 
"65+", "18 - 24", "35 - 44", "18 - 24", "18 - 24", "55 - 64", 
"65+"), Ethnicity = c("White or Caucasian", "Asian or Asian American", 
"White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian", "Hispanic or Latino", 
"White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian", 
"White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian", 
"White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian", 
"White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian", 
"Hispanic or Latino", "White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian", 
"White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian", "Hispanic or Latino", 
"White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian", 
"Black or African American", "Black or African American,White or     Caucasian", 
"White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian"), Ethnicity_Other = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), States = c("Texas", 
"Texas", "Ohio", "Texas", "Puerto Rico", "New Hampshire", "South         Carolina", 
"Texas", "Texas", "Texas", "Ohio", "Ohio", "Michigan", "New Jersey", 
"Texas", "North Carolina", "Florida", "Texas", "South Carolina", 
"Illinois", "New York", "New York", "Texas", "Ohio", "Virginia", 
"North Carolina", "Georgia", "Rhode Island", "Oregon", "Florida"
), Education = c("Master's degree", "Bachelor's degree in college (4-year)", 
"Bachelor's degree in college (4-year)", "Master's degree", "Master's degree", 
"Less than high school degree", "Some college but no degree", 
"Master's degree", "Master's degree", "Some college but no degree", 
"Bachelor's degree in college (4-year)", "Master's degree", "Associate     degree in college (2-year)", 
"Doctoral degree", "Master's degree", "Bachelor's degree in college (4-year)", 
"Some college but no degree", "Master's degree", "Associate degree in college (2-year)", 
"Master's degree", "Some college but no degree", "Bachelor's degree in college (4-year)", 
"Master's degree", "Some college but no degree", "Bachelor's degree in college (4-year)", 
"Master's degree", "Bachelor's degree in college (4-year)", "Bachelor's degree in college (4-year)", 
"Bachelor's degree in college (4-year)", "Bachelor's degree in college (4-    year)"
), `MEAN Income` = c(30000, 140000, 150000, 60000, 80000, 30000, 
30000, 120000, 150000, 60000, 30000, 40000, 40000, 0, 150000, 
150000, 150000, 40000, 150000, 140000, 40000, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 
150000, 40000, 150000, 80000, 60000, 80000), Income = c("Less than     $30,000", 
"$130,001 to $150,000", "More than $150,000", "$50,001 to $70,000", 
"$70,001 to $90,000", "Less than $30,000", "Less than $30,000", 
"$110,001 to $130,000", "More than $150,000", "$50,001 to $70,000", 
"Less than $30,000", "$30,000 to $50,000", "$30,000 to $50,000", 
"NA", "More than $150,000", "More than $150,000", "More than $150,000", 
"$30,000 to $50,000", "More than $150,000", "$130,001 to $150,000", 
"$30,000 to $50,000", "$90,001 to $110,000", "$90,001 to $110,000", 
"$90,001 to $110,000", "More than $150,000", "$30,000 to $50,000", 
"More than $150,000", "$70,001 to $90,000", "$50,001 to $70,000", 
"$70,001 to $90,000"), mean.partystrength = c(3.875, 2.875, 2.375, 
3.5, 2.625, 3.125, 3.375, 3.125, 3.25, 3.625, 3.375, 3.5, 2.875, 
3, 2.75, 2.625, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 3.125, 3.25, 3.375, 2.875, 3.125, 
3.125, 3, 2.875, 2.125, 2.375, 3.5), mean.traitrep = c(2.5, 2.625, 
2.25, 2.625, 2.75, 1.875, 2.75, 2.875, 2.75, 3, 2.875, 3, 3.375, 
2, 2.375, 2.375, 1.75, 1.75, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2.375, 3, 2.375, 2.75, 
1.625, 2.625, 2.25, 2.125), mean.traitdem = c(2.25, 2.625, 2.375, 
2.75, 2.625, 2.125, 1.875, 3, 2, 2.5, 2.875, 2.125, 2.75, 2.125, 
3, 2.375, 2.75, 1.75, 2.25, 3, 4, 2.75, 2, 3, 2.75, 2.375, 1.75, 
3.125, 2.375, 2.625), mean.leegauthor = c(1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 
2, 3), mean.legit = c(1.71428571428571, 3.28571428571429,         2.42857142857143, 
2.42857142857143, 2.14285714285714, 1.28571428571429, 1.42857142857143, 
1.14285714285714, 2.14285714285714, 1.28571428571429, 1.28571428571429, 
2, 2.28571428571429, 3.28571428571429, 2.14285714285714, 1.14285714285714, 
2.14285714285714, 2, 1.57142857142857, 3.28571428571429, 3.57142857142857, 
1.71428571428571, 1.85714285714286, 3.71428571428571, 2.42857142857143, 
1.85714285714286, 2.57142857142857, 3.28571428571429, 1.57142857142857, 
4)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

[image: Original data of traits/emotions]

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` fortmat? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(mydata2, 30))`.

Comment: Note that it doesn't make sense to reference a data frame in `ggplot()` and another in `aes()`. In fact, the purpose of `aes()` is that you can just reference the variable names. In regards to the chart itself, I don't understand its logic. It strongly suggests that, say, "happy" is in between "angry" and "annoyed".

Comment: Then "hateful" is between "joy" and "relaxed".

Comment: A **minimal** reproducible example would go a long way to make it easier for others to help you. Also, as already mentioned in comments above the code is realy weird (i.e. different data.frames in call to ggplot() and call to geom_point() for no reason, and then not even using `data` argument, using the mean values for y-axis, scales are a a bit of a mess, etc... ;

Comment: @dario 

Thank  you all for your responses! This is my very first time learning R, so I'm not sure how to answer your comments above and quite unfamiliar with how to write the data (I've been looking at a LOT of YouTube videos). I will add the survey question I used to measure these results.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you comment! This is my first time using R, and I am unsure how to add the dput. I've added the survey question I used to measure the results if that helps at all. Thank you again!

Comment: Run the `dput` instruction in my comment then copy its output and paste it in the question.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  oh ok got it. Thank you!

Comment: Hi OP : The plot makes sense now based on your dataset, but the column you map to the y axis is `mean.traitdem`, which is numeric and spans up until a value of 4.  How are those values mapped to your list of "disgusted", "relaxed", "hateful", etc, and in what order?  You can specify that as a relabeling of the y axis, but you'll need to identify what number corresponds to what emotion.

Comment: @chemdork123 Thanks for your feedback! I'm new to R so not sure how to relabel them as of yet... 1 would be low feelings, while 5 would be strong feelings towards each emotion. I noticed the values for mean.traitdem didn't exceed 4, whereas mean.traitrep went up to 5. Is this still a good way of representing the data you think?

Comment: Well, it's not too clear how the survey question shared translates to the dataset you shared.  If mean.traitdem and mean.treatrep, represent the average value in the 1-5 scale among those who answered the survey, for democrats and republicans, that's clear.  What's not clear is how the emotions are distributed and identified in your data.  If they are represented as numbers, then which number corresponds to which emotion, and which column in your dataset should be mapped to the emotion?

Comment: @chemdork123 I see, I haven't identified the emotions in this dataset, as I aggregated a mean for the rating scale. Perhaps that's the mistake I made. I've added an image of the data before I aggregated it. So per your suggestion, I can use a number for  each emotion?

Comment: Yes, if you aggregate the data for all emotions.. .it's fine to get an overall "emotional investment", but you are not going to pull out the individual emotions from that.  The emotions themselves are nominal data, not ordinal.  In other words, they don't line up on a numeric scale very easily here.  Where does "Relaxed" fall among "Joy" and "Disgusted"?  I think it's okay to show overall engagement by aggregating your data, but show that while keeping the emotions there.  If you want to share that dataset, we can help with ways to represent that.  Depends on how many responses you have.

Comment: @chemdork123 Thank you so much, I've spent almost 3 full days trying to search for how to do it and I'm not getting very far. Your help is very much appreciated! How do I go about sending  through an excel file?

Comment: Share a dataset via `dput()` as you have - Excel and csv files are discouraged from sharing, since links breaks and most won't click them anyway.  I would open a new question to explain a bit (and close this one).  If your dataset is too large, you can take a representative sample with:  `dput(df[sample(1:nrow(df), 30),])`.  That takes a representative sample of 30 lines from your dataset.  Better than using `head()`, which only takes off the top.

Comment: @chemdork123 you're the best, thank you!

Comment: Great to see that you have included some data. However, there is no data on different emotions. Also, can you find a plot (google) which looks like something you would like to create? People are usually really good at helping when they 1) know what you need and 2) have the data to make it happen.

Comment: @MagnusNordmo Thanks Magnus! I just posted another way of asking this question with the raw data here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63004232/how-to-plot-a-rating-scale-in-r
(I will figure out how to close this question!)