# How to plot a rating scale in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

What is the best way to represent the following trait rating scale? I'd like to label the traits (8 traits) and degrees or each emotion (1 being low feelings, 5 being strong feelings), across the democratic and republican parties? Do I need to aggregate the items? I'm new to R and not sure how to tackle this.

Survey question and scale:

"Below is a list of feelings or moods that could be caused by an object. Please use the list below to describe how the U.S. FEDERAL parties (and its elected officials) make you feel. If the word definitely describes how a party makes you feel, then choose the number 5. If you decide that the word does not at all describe how the party makes you feel, then choose the number 1. Use the intermediate numbers between 1 and 5 to indicate responses between these two extremes."

[image: Scale]

Survey sample:

```
dput(df[Book3(1:nrow(df), 30),])

structure(list(TRAITDEM1 = c(3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4), TRAITDEM2 = c(3, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 
2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2), TRAITDEM3 = c(3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 
5), TRAITDEM4 = c(3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1), TRAITDEM5 = c(3, 
4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4), TRAITDEM6 = c(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1), TRAITDEM7 = c(3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 5), TRAITDEM8 = c(3, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 
2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1), TRAITREP1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1), TRAITREP2 = c(1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 
5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5), TRAITREP3 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), TRAITREP4 = c(1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
5, 2, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 
1), TRAITREP5 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TRAITREP6 = c(1, 
5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 1, 
5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 1, 3), TRAITREP7 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2), TRAITREP8 = c(1, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 
1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5), PARTYID_Strength = c(5, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 3, 1, 6, 6, 1, 7, 8, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 
1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 7, 6, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

"PartyID_Strength" represents 8 measures of political parties:
1 - Strong Democrat
2 - Not very strong Democrat
3 - Strong Republican
4 - Not very strong Republican
5 - Independent
6 - Independent - Democrat
7 - Independent - Republican
8 - Other

I tried it this way (graph below) but it's still not plotting the remaining four traits:

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 2):

### Cleaning the data

In order to solve your problem, we have to transform your data, in order to convert it into *tidy* format.

#### Observation

There are few particular problems with your original dataset:

- Data are in a *wide format*, i.e. most of the columns from your data frame, can be represented by 3 variables;
- Names of the variables are not self-explanatory. Names are in upper case which, by itself, does not hold any useful information, they are not readable and not good for typing/writing.
- There is additional information we can extract from the variable names: Party and Feelings toward the Party. First one is an abbreviation ('dem' or 'rep') second one is the numerically encoded feeling towards the political party. However the order of numbers encoding the feeling does not reflect natural order of emotions from the disgust up to joy;
- Variable `PARTYID_Strength` is numerically encoded *Political Party [self-]Identification* it also does not reflect natural order from strongest democrats through independent towards strongest republicans;

#### Plan

1. Convert data from *wide* into *long* format using all variables starting with `TRAIT`, and leaving `PARTYID_Strength` variable unchanged;
2. Extract useful information from the `TRAIT...` variables (Political Party, Feelings Toward the Party);
3. Convert all numerically encoded variables into the factors with reasonably ordered levels;
4. Give all variables meaningful names;
5. Summarize the data;

#### Transformations

We need to create several lookup tables, which will simplify the workflow.

*Affiliation* lookup table:

```
aff_lookup <- c(
  'Strong Democrat',
  'Not very strong Democrat',
  'Strong Republican',
  'Not very strong Republican',
  'Independent',
  'Independent-Democrat',
  'Independent-Republican',
  'Other'
)
```

We can further order `aff_lookup` by this vector:

```
aff_order = c(1, 2, 6, 5, 7, 4, 3, 8)
```

*Emotions/Feelings* lookup table:

```
emo_lookup <- c(
  'Delighted',    
  'Angry',
  'Happy',
  'Annoyed',
  'Joy',
  'Hateful',
  'Relaxed',
  'Disgusted'
)
```

And we can order `emo_lookup` by this vector:

```
emo_order <- emo_order <- c(8, 6, 2, 4, 7, 3, 1, 5)
```

*Political party* lookup table:

```
party_lookup <- c(
  dem = 'National Democratic Party',
  rep = 'National Republican Party'
)
```

Finally, with all helper variables, we can transform our data into desirable form.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %<>%
  rename_all(tolower) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols          = starts_with('trait'),
    names_to      = c('party', 'emotion'),
    names_pattern = 'trait(dem|rep)(\\d)',
    values_to     = 'score'
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    party = factor(party_lookup[party]),
    affiliation = factor(
      aff_lookup[partyid_strength], 
      levels = aff_lookup[aff_order]
      ),
    emotion = factor(
      emo_lookup[as.numeric(emotion)], 
      levels = emo_lookup[emo_order]
      )
  ) %>%
  group_by(party, emotion, affiliation) %>%
  summarise(score = median(score)) %>%
  ungroup()

head(dat)

## A tibble: 6 x 4
#  party                     emotion   affiliation                score
#  <fct>                     <fct>     <fct>                      <dbl>
#1 National Democratic Party Disgusted Strong Democrat                1
#2 National Democratic Party Disgusted Not very strong Democrat       2
#3 National Democratic Party Disgusted Independent-Democrat           2
#4 National Democratic Party Disgusted Independent                    3
#5 National Democratic Party Disgusted Independent-Republican         3
#6 National Democratic Party Disgusted Not very strong Republican     5
```

### Plot the data

#### Plan

Now we can plot the data, as two separate plots for Democrats and Republicans with Affiliation (Political Party Identification) on X-axis and Emotions (Feelings) on Y-axis.

Each Emotion/Affilation point is going to be represented as a bar with the height of the bar representing the Score.

We can also add color encoding to our plot. From my point of view, encoding Emotions/Feelings with a color gradient from red (Disgust) to green (Joy) could help as to gather the internal structure of our data.

#### Plot

```
dat %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x      = affiliation, 
      y      = as.numeric(emotion) +  (score / max(score) * .95) / 2, 
      height = (score / max(score) * .95), 
      width  = .95,
      fill   = emotion,
      label  = score
      )
    ) +
  geom_tile(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(size = 3.5, color = 'gray25', alpha = .75) +
  facet_wrap(~ party, scales = 'free') +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'RdYlGn') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = sort(emo_order), labels = emo_lookup[emo_order]) +
  labs(x = 'Affiliations', y = 'Emotions') +
  ggthemes::theme_tufte() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x  = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y  = element_text(hjust = 0, vjust = -0.025),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  )
```

Which gives as following figure:

[image]

#### Explanation

There is a trick with this plot: it looks like a series of barplots, bot it is not real barplots (by the fact, not functionally).

What I do:

The core of this solution is the use of `geom_tile()` for each data point. It is just a rectangle (square by default) with geometrical center of mass determined by the given coordinates (Affilation, Emotion).

Both Affilation and Emotion are factors, not numerics. And it is OK for Affiliation, because we want only to position our *tile* according to the Affiliation it represents.

It is more complicated with Emotion, because we want to position each tile according to the Emotion it represents, but also we want to encode Score by the height of the tile.

To define the height of the tile we use `height` parameter within the `aes()`. We want our tile height to be less or equall to one (with 0.05 offset) so the tiles between let say Angry and Annoyed do not overlap. That's why we use `(score / max(score) * .95` for the `height` parameter.

We also need to give different y-coordinates for each tile, so the center of the tile is placed not on the imaginary line representing each emotion, but half-height up. So when tile is drawn, it's center (on y-axis) is placed half-height up from the "base line" and the tile extends half-height up and down, creating a fake barplot. That's what the following line of code does  `as.numeric(emotion) +  (score / max(score) * .95) / 2`.

We also give a tile a fixed width of .95 by `width  = .95`, file the tile with *Red-Yellow-Green* gradient and lable each tile with the relevant Score.

The rest are just decorations. However, note how we relable the Y-axis. Because, as it defined in `aes()` it is continuous scale, but we want to make it *fake discrete axis* we use this row:

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = sort(emo_order), labels = emo_lookup[emo_order])
```

Here we just use our `emo_order` to say that we want breaks for integers from 1 to 8, and after that we label this breaks with feelings from ordered `emo_lookup` table.

Comment: and how would extend the "score" legend to five? thank you, you are a lifesaver!

Comment: @LisaByers I have questions concerning stacked barchart. We are still talking about the same layout: party_id_strength on the X and trate on the Y? Or you have your own design in mind?

Comment: yes the layout is the same :) I was thinking to use the colour scheme in my graph that I posted above (but with a blue hues or gradient for Democratic and red hues or gradient for Republican). thank you again!

Comment: I am sorry, I was away, I will see what I can do. You are welcome, I'm glad to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218324/discussion-between-utubun-and-lisa-byers).

Comment: hope you're well! I sent you a message in the chat but I think it was closed. I ended up changing the colour for the scale: https://imgur.com/a/2WEyA1D
Would you mind helping me to change the Republican section to a red gradient (as I did a blue gradient for the Democratic party)? THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: @LisaByers Oh, yes, don't worry I will look at it. Just a bit latter, ok?